# Spring RestTemplate - Read different object type based on http status code?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have client and server applications, both written in spring using Java.
I am using `RestTemplate` to call server from client.

Server returns different response object, depending on result of operation.
 Simplified code:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> saveSomething (Object something) {
    boolean saved = save(something); //save logic
    if(saved)
        return new ResponseEntity<OKObject>(okObject,HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorObject>(errorObject,HttpStatus.FAILED); 
}
```

I want to be able to read those responses on client by status code,
 but RestTemplate offers only to read one type, e.g. `<Object_type>.class`;
and offers status code AFTER the `.getForEntity(...)` operation was executed -
 when response type is already returned.
What I want in pseudo code on client side:

```
public void saveSomething(Object toSave) {
     ResTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
     ResponseEntity<Object> response = template.getForEntity(url,Object.class);
     if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
         OKObject ok = (OKObject) response.getBody();
         //some work with ok object
     }
     if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FAILED) {
         ErrorObject errorObject = (ErrorObject) response.getBody();
         //some work with errorObject
     }
}
```

Is this possible in some non-hacky, clean way ? I read about setting response type as `String.class` and parse it afterwards, or reading `Object.class` (returns `LinkedHashMap`) and parse it.
Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to introduce a common response which includes both ok and error (one of them is null)

```
publi class CommonResponseObject {
    private OKObject okObject;
    private ErrorObject errorObject;
    public CommonResponseObject(OKObject okObject) {
        this.okObject=okObject;
    }
    public CommonResponseObject(ErrorObject errorObject) {
        this.errorObject=errorObject;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
public ResponseEntity<CommonResponseObject > saveSomething (Object something) {
    boolean saved = save(something); //save logic
    if(saved)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new CommonResponseObject(okObject),HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new CommonResponseObject(errorObject),HttpStatus.FAILED); 
}
```

and process the results

```
public void saveSomething(Object toSave) {
     ResTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
     ResponseEntity<CommonResponseObject> response = template.getForEntity(url,CommonResponseObject.class);
     if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
         OKObject ok = response.getBody().getOkObject();
     }
     if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FAILED) {
         ErrorObject errorObject = response.getBody().getErrorObject();
     }
}
```

Comment: That is really bad, because with more responseObjects you would transfer more redundant data; and also in code there would be many response classes wrapped in one just to be able to get response. This is the hacky way I dont want. But thanks for response.

Comment: Just a bit more.. one of the ok/error is always null. You can configure serialization to skip nulls. The extra info (in case of json) is just the field name ok or error.

Comment: You can also just send a String, check status and deserialize the string to Ok or Error object

Comment: Custom wrapper objects and string deserialization may not look good in code, but still I am looking for best solution AVAILABLE, and this may be it. Thanks :)